# which language can compile independent exe file

Tags: winapi, compiler-construction, exe

I wonder if anyone can suggest me on which language I can compile exe file which is indepdent like NSIS but more powerful. something which can I run on Win XP+ without any framework (.net / whatever), but external Dlls are accepted.

thanks.

Comment: Delphi, Lazarus - no external DLLs and dependencies.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2585998/62576

Comment: BTW, I think it's a mistake to discount .Net on any contemporary version of Windows.  The .Net runtime is basically as much a part of the OS as gdi32.dll or USER.EXE.  IMHO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By mentioning "NSIS" I understand that you want to create a self-extracting installer executable. Right?

"NSIS" seems to be one of the most powerful ones available so if you want to have something more powerful you'll have to write the installer in a regular programming language.

If you are not interested in installers:

There are many programming languages available for Windows that can generate stand-alone executables:

C, C++, Pascal, Visual Basic, ...

(Note that the latest version of Visual Basic will generate .NET executables)

The open-source and free variants of the programming languages are:

- C, C++, Assembler: GCC (available in different variants: MingW, Cygwin, Dev-Cpp, ...)
- Pascal: FreePascal (a variant is the graphically-oriented "Lazarus")

Of course you can also buy a professional compiler.

(Using C and C++ you can also create DLL libraries.)