# Building Lua scripts alongside project

Tags: c++, lua

How can I build my C++ project to include all the Lua files in just one executable? I don't want people being able to edit the Lua files and alter the game.

Is it possible, and is it ethical?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194520/creating-standalone-lua-executables.

Comment: you can also do it textually like in [premake](https://github.com/annulen/premake/blob/master/scripts/embed.lua) and statically obfuscate (i.e. encrypt or compress) the strings if you want messing with the scripts to be harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want to put all Lua sources into your executable, so you need this:

- A means of mapping file-names to the Lua files:

  ```
  char lua_files[]={
      "filename1\0filecontents1",
      "filename2\0filecontents2",
      0,
  };
  ```

  This can be created automatically, by a script reading your directory of Lua files when building.
  Optionally, it might even pre-compile the files, so you can remove the parser from your embeddded Lua library.
- A custom loader:
  Write a short Lua C function, which searches the array and returns `load` and a string encompassing the found filecontents as a Lua string.
  Register it by placing it into `package.searchers`.

If you later want to allow loading custom scripts somehow, retain the old searchers and make sure you somehow require files not in your sources.

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite get my head around what you mean.

Comment: I think I understand it somewhat now, let's say Lua file `test.lua` is in `lua` folder would I put in lua_files[] `lua\test.lua`? Just want clarification.

Comment: Yes `lua_file = {"lua/test.lua\0require \"World\":execute()--Or Whatever your file contains.", 0}`

Answer (score 2):

Use "[embedded bytecode](http://luajit.org/running.html#opt_b)" feature of LuaJIT:

> To statically embed the bytecode of a module in your application, generate an object file and just link it with your application.
>
> require() tries to load embedded bytecode data from exported symbols (in *.exe or lua51.dll on Windows) and from shared libraries in package.cpath.

Example:

```
luajit -b test.lua test.obj                 # Generate object file
# Link test.obj with your application and load it with require("test")
```