# gcc error on trying to compile lua file

Tags: gcc, lua

I am trying to create executable from lua file using following method:

I use bintocee utility (from: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BinToCee) to convert myfile.lua to code.c . I then use following main.c (from: [Creating standalone Lua executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194520/creating-standalone-lua-executables))

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  lua_newtable(L);
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    lua_pushnumber(L, i);
    lua_pushstring(L, argv[i]);
    lua_rawset(L, -3);
  }
  lua_setglobal(L, "arg");
#include "code.c" 
  lua_close(L);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I give command:

```
gcc main.c -o myfile.exe
```

However, I get following error:

```
/tmp/ccyIOC0O.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `luaL_newstate'
main.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs'
main.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `lua_createtable'
main.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `lua_pushnumber'
main.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `lua_pushstring'
main.c:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `lua_rawset'
main.c:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `lua_setfield'
main.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `luaL_loadbuffer'
main.c:(.text+0xea): undefined reference to `lua_pcall'
main.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `lua_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am working on Linux Debian Stable (updated). Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a litlle idea about `lua`, but it clearly needs some library to be linked with.

Comment: I tried installing liblua5.1 and liblua5.1-dev but same error persists.

Comment: Yo need to link with. Something like `gcc main.c -llua -o myfile.exe` (dunno about the actual name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you installed `liblua-5.1-dev`, I assume you are on Debian or a derivative.  There, you have to link with `-llua5.1`, like this:

```
gcc -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/lua5.1 main.c -llua5.1
```

Comment: Yes, it works. It will be helpful to all if you can briefly explain all the options used here.