# MinGw "Luac" creates .out files instead of .exe files

Tags: windows, lua, mingw, luac

When I use the MinGW Lua compiler, I get a Linux .out file, instead of a Windows .exe file. Is there a way I can compile it as an executable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194520/creating-standalone-lua-executables

Comment: Not exactly.⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: For the record, luac does not generate executables in any platform. It outputs a binary file containing precompiled scripts.

Comment: Ah ok. I was just wanting conformation on the subject. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: There is possibility to 'compile' (bundle) `.lua` to `.exe` using modified luac or use existing solutions like https://luvit.io/install.html